# How to get a item history only that it was selected in Open Menu by right clicking

Tags: javascript, menu-item

I want to ask how to get id of element which was clicked by right clicking in open menu. I must know ID of this element to show only that history the element what was clicked fom open menu:

[image]

Comment: Have you added any custom option in the context menu?

Comment: No, how could I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom Action - 'List Item Menu' using SharePoint Designer and navigate the user on click wherever you want to redirect.  More information on how to create custom action is [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/09/27/how-to-create-a-quick-step-and-custom-action-to-start-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

[image]
[image]

[image]